# UTF-8 character encoding is not working for spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application and it uses post to store the content using UTF-8 and read the contents also using UTF-8.
When i use any of the chinese characters i am getting the response as "�" instead of the actual value.
While I have set the UTF-8 for all incoming and outgoing values.

I have also wrote a filter which sets the character encoding for httpservletrequest and httpservletresponse which is being called but still it is not working.

This is primarily a REST API and not returning the actual value instead it returns "?".

I am using Spring Boot 1.2.3.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46466157/utf-8-characters-not-seen-in-jetty-angular-4-spring-framework/51374370#51374370

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your database character set to utf8mb4 which is superset of utf-8, Click [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8239/how-to-easily-convert-utf8-tables-to-utf8mb4-in-mysql-5-5) will help you.